# Does End of Days affect cards underneath another card (e.g. The Dreamer's defeated Projections)?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

Fanatic has a card called "End of Days" that destroys most every card in play:

> At the start of the Environment turn, destroy all cards in play, other than this card, character cards, and Relics.
>
> Then, destroy this card.

Several villains, such as the Dreamer, can place cards underneath them:

> Whenever a Projection card is destroyed, it is placed under this card. At the start of the Villain turn, if there are (H) times 2 cards underneath this card, the heroes win the game.

Does End of Days affect these "underneath" cards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this in the app version of the game.

1. The cards under The Dreamer they are destroyed
2. The cards are put back under The Dreamer, per its effect
3. If some other card would interact (Like Savage Mana), that takes precedence and would be destroyed afterwards

Also don't forget that it's the players that choose which effect resolve first and which cards are destroyed first.

Comment: I changed your run-on sentence into a list for clarity. If I missed something or you otherwise don't like the change, feel free to edit or revert it.

Comment: Thanks ! Also don't forget that it's the players that choose which effect resolve first and which cards are destroyed first.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at play here. First is that once a projection card is destroyed and placed under the dreamers card they are no longer in play. Second is that even when they are under the dreamers card they are sill projections so if they where able to get destroyed they would be placed right back under the card per the rules of the card.

Comment: So is your second point moot because the cards are out of play (and not accessible to End of Days) due to your first point? I ask because other villains, like Time Pirate, can have cards underneath her, but not due to card destruction.